# Getting error 1004 when deleting filtered rows?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to delete rows after filtering on a column that indicates whether an item is Vendor Only (Yes/No).

I want to delete all rows where the values under that column indicate Yes. However, I run into an error when I select the visible rows to delete.

I've used this same code for other macros before but this time it did not work.

```
Dim VisibleCell As Long 'Variable to count the number of visible cells after filtering

VisibleCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A3:A50000"))
Range("Table1").Select

'Filter and remove all Vendor Only items
Rows("2:2").Select 'Find column for Vendor Only and filter for Yes values
    Cells.Find(What:="Vendor Item?", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

MyCol = ActiveCell.Column
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=MyCol, Criteria1:= _
    "Yes", Operator:=xlAnd
VisibleCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A3:A50000"))

If VisibleCell > 0 Then
    Range("A3:A2000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete 'Error occurs here
End If
```

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow!* be sure to check out the [tour] (it earns you a badge too!) ...I think you're over-complicating your task  Do you know how to do this manually, with AutoFilter?  If so, record a macro of yourself doing whatever actions you want, and you code will be 90% written for you.

Comment: see: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: Hi,that's originally what I did.. I recorded the macro and tweaked it for my own use. It has worked for my previous file but not this one for some reason..

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `ListObject`, you can refer to a `ListColumn` by its header ("Vendor Item?") instead of `Find`ing the cell in row 2.

Also, I'd refer to the `Index` of that `ListColumn`, not its `Column`, when you want to filter. The `Index` returns its column number within the table, while `Column` would be its column on the sheet. The two would coincide if your table starts in Column A (which it sounds like is the case here), but `Index` is more robust if your table's position changes.

Finally, no need to `Activate` or `Select`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteVendorOnly()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim colIndex As Integer
    Dim rngToDelete As Range

    Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")  ' Change to your sheet name
    colIndex = tbl.ListColumns("Vendor Item?").Index

    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=colIndex, Criteria1:="Yes"

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngToDelete = tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response! I just tested your code above and still ran into the same error on the "rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete" part... :(:(:(

Comment: Is there another table on your sheet?

Comment: OK.. so I changed the code to " rngToDelete.Rows.Delete" and for some reason that one worked instead. I am not sure why .EntireRow is giving me issues.... :(

Comment: Nope, I only have 1 table in my sheet.

Comment: had a similar problem `EntireRow.Delete` is the way it worked (there are other tables (vertically arranged) on the sheet and other stuff and the tables are not starting on column A)